# Does enrolling user bring all user's devices under Alexa for Business account?

Tags: alexa-for-business

If I invite and enroll a user in my Alexa for Business account, will all devices that user owns show up in "Shared devices" list?

Or do I have to run the setup tool on all devices then only they will show up in "Shared devices" list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After research and experimentation, it turns out, only devices that go through setup through Alexa for Business deployment tool show up in the "Shared devices" list. Devices of the "enrolled" user, do not show in this list.